# How do you schedule a Java Task (cron) on app engine flexible?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

How do you create a Java long running scheduled task (like every hour) on **app engine flexible** environment?

The only docs I can find are for **standard** environment:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/cron

Is there anything in the platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. [Documentation is here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml) for Flexible/Java.

To upload your cron jobs, you must specify the cron.yaml as a parameter to the following gcloud command:

```
gcloud app deploy cron.yaml
```

To delete all cron jobs, change the cron.yaml file to just contain:

```
cron:
```

The cron.yaml file lives in the `WEB-INF` directory of your application (alongside app.yaml). The following is an example cron.yaml file:

```
cron:
- description: daily summary job
  url: /tasks/summary
  schedule: every 24 hours
```

Comment: How can this be used on the local development server?